# QDialog modality vs QMainWindow

Tags: qt, modal-dialog, qmainwindow, qdialog

I have a QMainWindow object parent to a QDialog Object. When I call the QDialog with `exec()` it stays open, but I can't use the QMainWindow at the same time. If I use `show()` instead, the QDialog opens and hides immediately after.

I know this relates to the modality flag of the QDialog, but it does not have a `Qt::Modeless` flag, so I'm a bit lost.

**Question:** How can I display a `QDialog` and still be able to interact with its parent `QMainWindow`?

My code for the QDialog object:

```
class catalog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit catalog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~catalog();

private:
    Ui::catalog *ui;
};
```

How I'm calling it:

```
void DiagramWindow::showCatalog()
{
    catalog catalog(this);
    catalog.exec();
}
```

Comment: Have you read the examples? https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#code-examples

Comment: @cmannett85 I looked for them, but hadn't seen the one you posted yet, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It closes, because `QDialog::show()` method is asynchronous and your `catalog` object is destroyed right after your code leaves `DiagramWindow::showCatalog()` method. You should rewrite it like this:

```
void DiagramWindow::showCatalog()
{
    catalog *c = new catalog(this);
    c->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    c->show();
}
```